# Novel - people in bio/eco-dome when virus is released

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I'm attempting to locate a book for my mother she read a long time ago. Her description of the novel is that people are in a bio-dome/eco-dome and while in there a virus is released. Their contact with people outside the dome disappears and so they send one person out and she dies. There also is a Eskimo character who is immune... Anyone know the title of this book?! I know it's not a lot to go on. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite the same but similar: *[Mother Grimm](https://www.sfsite.com/11b/moth21.htm)* by Catherine Wells. The virus is outside, one immune woman flees the dome. There is no Eskimo mentioned.

> The Biodome is an isolated domed oasis in the middle of a ravaged Earth. Outside is full of mystery and disease, where those infected by a deadly virus are sent to die, a land of warring tribes and half-crazed factions living on the edge of sanity. Twila Grimm, who has lived her entire life in the Biodome, tries to learn the secrets of her origin and solve the mysteries surrounding her.